# Could not evaluate: undefined class/module Puppet::Util::TagSet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, svn, puppet

I'm having an issue with the latest puppet version and a module called vcsdeploy. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with Ruby and it's own idiosyncrasies, so I'm hoping someone with a little more experience can point me in the right direction.

The module in question can be found [here](https://github.com/practicalclouds/pclouds-vcsdeploy) in all it's glory. The particular issue I'm experiencing is an error at line 194 in lib/puppet/provider/vcsdeploy/svn.rb: *"Could not evaluate: undefined class/module Puppet::Util::TagSet"*

For those who don't want to spelunk the source code, here's the code that's causing the error:

```
valid_options = [ 'path', 'owner', 'group', 'dirmode', 'filemode', 'source', 'user', 'pass', 'name', 'version', 'selrange', 'selrole', 'seltype', 'seluser', 'templates' ]
@resource_copy = {}

debug "creating resource_copy for #{resource[:name]}"
valid_options.each {|option|
  if (option && resource[option.to_sym])
    @resource_copy[option.to_sym] = resource[option.to_sym]
  end
}
```

I would assume that Puppet::Util::TagSet is used to some degree elsewhere throughout puppet and it's various modules however this is the only one that's causing a problem.

Anyone got any pointers that I could use to start this investigation?

More System Information:

> Operating System: **CentOS 6.5**
>
> Installation Method: **RPM packages**
>
> Foreman Version: **1.5**
>
> Puppet Version: **3.5.1**

I have also verified that the file tag_set.rb exists at the location:

> /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/tag_set.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the module fails to document is that it requires Puppet `3.3` which introduced this piece of code (see the [commit](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/commit/61e6ede8402ff61ada6382aedc4feb7e41d39844#diff-99bb0a1888cdfc6b714682b64102ecd4)).

Comment: Hey, unfortunately I forgot to mention the puppet version that I'm running, which is 3.5.1. I've updated my original post with more information, thanks for taking the time to have a look.

Comment: And the agent in question is surely running the same Puppet version?

Comment: I....Wow. I'm an idiot. Thank you so much :) It was running a 3.2 version of puppet, explicitly set by puppet itself for some reason. Sanity has been attained once more!